# What is the difference between opencv function cvcvtcolor and cvtcolor

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new to c++ coding . can you tell me what is the difference between opencv function cvcvtcolor and cvtcolor ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cvCvtColor inputs and outputs parameters is cvArray reference image aka "IplImage"

Syntax: cvCvtColor(CvArr *src, CvArr *dst, int code)

cvtColor on the other hand using InputArray images aka "Mat"

Syntax: cvtColor(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int code)

Notice that cvArray (IplImage) is a reference address to the image, While InputArray (Mat) is the actual image.

As a practical test i have tried both with int code = CV_BGR2HSV, Surprisingly the output was too different, Both tested at same environment (Neon-light White Balance).

cvCvtColor on OpenCV 3.4.3

```
cvCvtColor(inputIplImage, outputIplImage, CV_BGR2HSV);
```

[image]

cvCvtColor on OpenCV 4.4.0

```
cvtColor(inputMat, outputMat, CV_BGR2HSV);
```

[image]

Finally you have to know that cvCvtColor Not exist anymore in OpenCV 4.4.0 as IplImage is deprecated and we have to use Mat instead, So I guess you will have to use cvtColor or Stick to the previous version 3.4.3

Answer (score 8):

There is no difference except that `cvCvtColor` is a simple wrapper for `cvtColor`.

1. `cvCvtColor` is C API - *deprecated*.
2. `cvtColor` is C++ API - *recommended*.

From opencv source[(1)](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4.9/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp#L4416)  you can see that the C API `cvCvtColor` is wrapper around the C++ `cvtColor` which does actual conversions like `RGB2GRAY` etc.

```
CV_IMPL void cvCvtColor( const CvArr* srcarr, CvArr* dstarr, int code )
{
    cv::Mat src = cv::cvarrToMat(srcarr), dst0 = cv::cvarrToMat(dstarr), dst = dst0;
    CV_Assert( src.depth() == dst.depth() );

    cv::cvtColor(src, dst, code, dst.channels());
    CV_Assert( dst.data == dst0.data );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

C: void cvCvtColor(const CvArr* src, CvArr* dst, int code)

C++: void cvtColor(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int code, int dstCn=0 )

That's the difference, cvCvtColor belongs to the old deprecated C API whereas cv::cvtColor belongs to the current C++ OpenCV API. Make use of the cv namespace as much as possible to avoid using legacy code.

Answer (score 2):

[They're equivalent](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor), except `cvtcolor` is the C++ API and `cvCvtColor` C API.

If you use C++, you only need to care about and are also recommend to use `cvtcolor`.